# htmlentities() not working properly on web hosting server

Tags: php, character-encoding

I'm using htmlentities() on user-inputted data and on my local server there are no problems. However, when I run the code on my web hosting server the character encoding seems messed up.

Example (using the string **åäö áàâ**);

```
Local server
[message] => &aring;&auml;&ouml; &aacute;&agrave;&acirc;

Output = åäö áàâ
```

however the result on my web hosting server is

```
Web hosting server
[message] => &Atilde;&yen;&Atilde;&curren;&Atilde;&para; &Atilde;&iexcl;&Atilde;&nbsp;&Atilde;&cent;

Output = Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶ Ã¡Ã Ã¢
```

The "charset problem" occurs when applying htmlentities() to the string. How do I fix it?

Comment: Just for a bit of debugging.. Have you used the correct encoding to the string? http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php for example?

Comment: Rather than editing your answer with a message that it's fixed, wait until you can mark your own answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it and this was the cause of the problem;

According to [php.net](http://php.net/htmlentities), PHP versions prior to 5.4.0 has 'ISO-8859-1' as default encoding. All I had to do was to simply change it to 'UTF-8' as in;

```
htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8');
```

(this was the first thing I tried though, but I wrote 'utf-8' in lower case which didn't work!!)

Answer (score 0):

Unicode uses more than one byte to represent each character. PHP will print both bytes as a separate char unless you filter it.

Try

```
htmlentities(mb_convert_encoding($s,'utf8'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your PHP page encoding *(the page itself)* is the same charset as `htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')`, in your case `UTF-8`. Also, make sure `default_charset = '';` in php.ini, or comment it out, with `;` before `default_charset`.

Comment: I tried making a completely fresh file [link](http://www.williamboman.com/profile/bajs.php) and I still get the same error on the web service server.

Comment: It's UTF-8 (without BOM) - always. Will the file encoding have an effect on user-inputted data though?